# vim "caught deadly signal HUP", what files are it preserving?

Tags: vim

I logged out, apparently forgetting to bring back a vim session to the foreground. As expected, vim spat out "Vim: caught deadly signal HUP" followed by "Vim: preserving files".

My question is: What files are being preserved? I guess those are the edited-but-unsaved files; where are those kept? How to I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `"Vim: caught deadly signal HUP" followed by "Vim: preserving files".`, all files which are editing are saved to swap files. According to `vim` manual:

```
The name of the swap file is normally the same as the file you are editing,
with the extension ".swp".
- On Unix, a '.' is prepended to swap file names in the same directory as the
  edited file.  This avoids that the swap file shows up in a directory
  listing.
- On MS-DOS machines and when the 'shortname' option is on, any '.' in the
  original file name is replaced with '_'.
- If this file already exists (e.g., when you are recovering from a crash) a
  warning is given and another extension is used, ".swo", ".swn", etc.
- An existing file will never be overwritten.
- The swap file is deleted as soon as Vim stops editing the file.
```

By default, swap file is stored in the same directory with original file. You can find it using this command:

```
ls -la .filename.swp
```

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm not sure what file it was editing, I'll just to a `find` for .sw files :-)

Comment: Just to update for posterity: I used `find / -regex '.*\.sw[nop]'` (bearing in mind that find's regex's are automatically anchored to ^ and $)